# Is is possible to using both subdomain and subcategory in wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, subdirectory, multisite, wpmu

I have:

```
domain.com
```

I also have

```
domain.com/site1
domain.com/site2
domain.com/site3
```

And now I want

```
site4.domain.com
```

Is it possible? And if yes, how?

I've been searching for many articles, comments... but no luck. And I double about this ability.

Comment: Are you using the WordPress MU Domain Mapping network plugin?

Comment: Hi, I tried that plugin but it's not help. Btw, I found the solution - WP Multinetwork.

Thanks for comment!

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: @deronimo I use WP Multinetwork plugin